Css slide show can't create a proper order with keyframes


.imageContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 640px; /* adjust as needed */
  overflow: hidden; 
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  object-fit: contain;
  opacity: 0;
}
.image:nth-child(1) {
  animation: slide 12s infinite;
}

.image:nth-child(2) {
  animation: slide2 12s infinite;
  animation-delay: 4s; /* 2nd image starts after 1st image disappears */
}

.image:nth-child(3) {
  animation: slide3 12s infinite;
  animation-delay: 8s; /* 3rd image starts after 2nd image disappears */
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% { transform: translateX(0); opacity: 1; }
  16% { transform: translateX(-100%); opacity: 0; } /* 1st image stays for 2s */
  33%, 100% { transform: translateX(-100%); opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes slide2 {
  0%, 33% { transform: translateX(100%); opacity: 0; }
  50% { transform: translateX(0); opacity: 1; } /* 2nd image stays for 2s */
  66% { transform: translateX(-100%); opacity: 0; }
  100% { transform: translateX(-100%); opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes slide3 {
  0%, 66% { transform: translateX(100%); opacity: 0; }
  83% { transform: translateX(0); opacity: 1; } /* 3rd image stays for 2s */
  100% { transform: translateX(-100%); opacity: 0; }
}
<div class="imageContainer">
  <img class="image" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/painting-mountain-lake-with-mountain-background_188544-9126.jpg" />
  <img class="image" src="https://images.ctfassets.net/hrltx12pl8hq/3Z1N8LpxtXNQhBD5EnIg8X/975e2497dc598bb64fde390592ae1133/spring-images-min.jpg" />
  <img class="image" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1322277517/photo/wild-grass-in-the-mountains-at-sunset.jpg?s=612x612&w=0&k=20&c=6mItwwFFGqKNKEAzv0mv6TaxhLN3zSE43bWmFN--J5w=" />
</div>



I have three images in html which have .image classname. Which I try to achieve is I am trying to make a slideshow loop around three images. Each image should stay min 2 secs, it can be 3 secs but all of them should stay same amount same amount of time.
I tried many combinations with keyframes this is one of my tries. The main problem which I encountered, I can't display first image enough. If I display it enough order breaks and it displays earlier when loop ends so 3rd image and first image concur at the same time.
Is there a fix for it? Or should I try something different?

Please add related HTML also - perhaps as a working snippet; so we may best assist you here

It looks like you tried to tackle the problem from "two ends" - you apply different animations, and with different delays. If you want the behavior for all three images to be the same - then you should probably use the same animation for all of them, and only modify the delay.

Thank you @CBroe for your suggestion. I removed slide2 3.. and just used only slide. It works fine.

Use one animation. Calculate how long each image will be visible, in other words time of slide in + time of being visible, let's say 1 second slide in + 2 seconds visible would be 3 seconds per image. If you want to use 3 images in total you have to multiply that and get 9 seconds total, this is your animation duration for all images. To calculate the keyframes you can now do 100% / 9 = 11.11%, so 0% should be positioned outside to the right, 11.11% and 33.33% should be the visible state and 44.44% and 100% should be outside to the left side.

side note: I would aim for the images to be the same size/aspect ratio to make it look smoother in the end.
